# Laravel 7 - Select only one row from a database and pass it to blade

Tags: laravel

I am trying to pass a row from database to blade. But I am getting the error message stating

`Undefined variable : tuser`

**Blade(multipage1)**

```
//Other Codes

<input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter email" value="@if($tuser){{$tuser->temp_email}}@endif">
```

**Controller**

```
$tuser = DB::table('temp_users')->where('referenceno',$reference)->first();
 if(!(is_null($tuser))){
 return view('multipage1',compact('tuser'));
}
```

***I also tried using***

```
$tuser = DB::table('temp_users')->where('referenceno',$reference)->first();
 if(!(is_null($tuser))){
 return view('multipage1')->with('tuser',$tuser);
}
```

But I am getting the same error

Comment: Dont need to check is_null use firstOrFail() instead of first(), if result is null, then it will throw a 404 error `$tuser = DB::table('temp_users')->where('referenceno',$reference)->firstOrFail();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best approach is :

**Controller**

```
$tuser = DB::table('temp_users')->where('referenceno',$reference)->first();
return view('multipage1',compact('tuser'));
```

notice the compact, I passed the variable name as string and without the $ sign

and your **View**

```
//Other Codes

<input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter email" value="{{$tuser->temp_email ?? ''}}">
```

Comment: I did that. That too resulted in an error. I shall update my code right away

Comment: @Skumar, did u make sure your code is exactly the same as mine?? also do you have $tuser  somewhere else in your blade? if you do you gonna have to use the same way for it  {{$tuser->other_attr ?? ''}}

Comment: Yes. I copied and pasted the answer. Also, I tried changing the variable name. Now it's giving me the `undefined variable` for the new variable as well

Comment: I think I got my problem. It was because of cache (after trying your code). Need to test more.

Answer (score 1):

```
 // First Create Model
// Using Eloquent Query
$tuse = TempUsers::where('referenceno',$reference)->first();

return view('multipage1',compact('tuser'));
```

Comment: I dont like Laravel Models, so I dont use them

Comment: Hello,Laravel Model is good concept. Usefult to relationship and other feature